# Social Feeds - Read another user feed don't work internal code error 58

Tags: 2013, social

I'm quite desperate, I working on project when I'd like to impersotane users and create post on behalf of them, read theirs feeds and according of those do some actions. I have figured out how to post on another user newsfeed, but still cannot read all. I have tried function GetFeedFor(), but this give you back just threads, no likes, no follows. I have been trying impersonate the process accordingly:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(myHostUrl))
            {
                SPUser userForContext = site.RootWeb.SiteUsers[account2];
                SPUserToken userToken = userForContext.UserToken;
                //create service context
                SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                //using Service Context Scope
                using (new SPServiceContextScope(serviceContext))
                {
                    //create profile manager for loading my test accounts
                    UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
                    UserProfile userProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(account2);
                    /*List all NewsFeeds*/
                    SPSocialFeedManager feedManager = new SPSocialFeedManager(userProfile, serviceContext, userToken);
                    //here is exception thrown away
                    SPSocialFeed feed =  feedManager.GetFeed(SPSocialFeedType.Personal, new SPSocialFeedOptions());
                    //this write post on user's newsfeed and works!
                    WritePost(feedManager, "Forth Test!");
                }
            }
```

Whole stack is here:

```
Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialException was unhandled
  HResult=6
  Message=The operation failed because an internal error occurred. Internal type name: Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException. Internal error code: 58.
  Source=Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles
  ErrorCode=6
  InternalErrorCode=58
  InternalMessage=ServerErrorSecurityTrimmer : No Security Trimmer found  : Correlation ID:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 : Date and Time : 13/09/2013 16:44:27
  InternalStackTrace=   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicroBlogEntity.SecurityTrimMicroFeed(List`1 mbThreads, SPMicrofeedRetrievalOptions retrievalOptions)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.SPMicrofeedThreadCollection.SecurityTrimMicroFeed(SPMicrofeedRetrievalOptions retrievalOptions)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.SPMicrofeedThreadCollection.Populate(SPMicrofeedRetrievalOptions retrievalOptions, SPMicrofeedContext context)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.SPMicrofeedManager.CommonGetFeedFor(SPMicrofeedRetrievalOptions retrievalOptions)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.SPMicrofeedManager.CommonPubFeedGetter(SPMicrofeedRetrievalOptions feedOptions, MicrofeedPublishedFeedType feedType, Boolean publicView)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.SPMicrofeedManager.GetMyPublishedFeed(SPMicrofeedRetrievalOptions feedOptions, MicrofeedPublishedFeedType typeOfPubFeed, Boolean ShowPublicView)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.ISocialFeedManagerProxy.ProxyGetFeed(SPSocialFeedType type, SPSocialFeedOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.c__DisplayClass2b.b__2a(ISocialFeedManagerProxy proxy)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.c__DisplayClass4b`1.b__4a()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialUtil.InvokeWithExceptionTranslation[T](ISocialOperationManager target, String name, Func`1 func)
  InternalTypeName=Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialUtil.TryTranslateExceptionAndThrow(Exception exception)
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialUtil.InvokeWithExceptionTranslation[T](ISocialOperationManager target, String name, Func`1 func)
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.S2SInvoke[T](String name, SPS2SAppExecutionContextBase context, Func`2 func, Boolean elevateForIsLocalCheck)
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.c__DisplayClass48`1.b__47()
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialUtil.InvokeWithExceptionTranslation[T](ISocialOperationManager target, String name, Func`1 func)
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.S2SInvoke[T](String name, MicroBlogEntity mbeTarget, Func`2 func, Boolean elevateForIsLocalCheck)
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.GetFeed(SPSocialFeedType type, SPSocialFeedOptions options)
       at SocialTest.CreatePost.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\m.bodocky\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SocialTest\SocialTest.CreatePost\Program.cs:line 54
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Hello, I'd like to ask MS guys to comment functions, especially for using user contexts. The failure of my program is in using the constructor: SPSocialFeedManager feedManager = new SPSocialFeedManager(userProfile, serviceContext, userToken); => userProfile - is user profile of user who's running this application; serviceContext - is from your my site collection; userToken - is user token of user which is object of your query!

Comment: Hello,<br/>this code does not work for me. It does not throw an exception but I always get the feed of the current user, no matter what UserToken I'm sending. I can test this behavior by running the code in a console app as different Windows users. I always get the feed of the user account the console is started with.
> Might this be a bug in SharePoint's social API? Best regards<br/>
Holger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working solution:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(myHostUrl))
            {
                //account1 is not current user
                SPUser userForContext = site.RootWeb.SiteUsers[account1];
                SPUserToken userToken = userForContext.UserToken;
                //create service context
                SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                //using Service Context Scope
                using (new SPServiceContextScope(serviceContext))
                {
                    //create profile manager for loading my test accounts
                    UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
                    // I'm getting user profile of my current user
                    UserProfile userProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(System.Environment.UserName);
                    SPSocialFeedManager feedManager = new SPSocialFeedManager(userProfile, serviceContext, userToken);
                    //It does work nicely!
                    SPSocialFeed feed =  feedManager.GetFeed(SPSocialFeedType.Personal, new SPSocialFeedOptions());
                }
            }
```